# this submit button is created with javascript and doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, button, submit

This submit button is created with JavaScript and doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Submit Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<form name="coba" method="POST" action="Menu.php">
<script>
//create submit button
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The  button needs to be in the form (or associated with the [*form* attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms)), not appended to the body. The form is missing a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above, the new button needs to be appended to the `form` and not directly to the `body`. So, to identify the form, the relevant code should be added too:

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Submit Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<form name="coba" id="coba" method="POST" action="Menu.php">
</form>
<script>
//create submit button
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    document.getElementById("coba").appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```